# How can I have configuration per worker role _instance_ (not role)

Tags: azure, quartz.net, azure-worker-roles

**Given**: One Worker role + several Quartz.net jobs. Quartz jobs are host-agnostic and are executed in Worker role.

A worker role can be scaled to multiple instances.

**The Goal is**: have the ability to define what job to run in what instance at runtime (or define it with configuration only, no code changes). For example:

- MyRole Instance 1: Job1, Job2, Job3
- MyRole Instance 2: Job4,
- MyRole Instance 3: Job4,
- MyRole Instance 4: Job4,
- MyRole Instance 5: Job5, Job6

In my example Job4 receives a lot of load. So I'd like it to run on more instances. And I also want it to be scalable at runtime (or at least via configuration, w/o code changes).

AFAIK it is not possible to have azure configuration per instance (only per role itself). Search online on similar issues haven't given any results.

**Question**: Did anybody have similar situation? What would be the best approach? Any other design advice is very appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is more of an architectural problem then one specific to Azure. The most common solution is to set up a "broker" that each instance/process reaches out to and asks for its individual workload. The challenge, regardless of the platform you are deploying the solution is how to a) identify the broker and b) ensure the "state" information being managed by the broker is persisted in case the broker process dies.

The most common approach to address these concerns in Azure is the use of a blob with a lease on it that allows the broker to be 'self elected' (the first process to get the lease is the broker), and stores both the address of the broker and the broker's state (metadata stored within the blob). You then put the logic for assigning jobs into this broker in a way that best suits your task distribution needs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It makes sense. In case of Azure, can you please clarify how exactly instances can ask a "broker" for a work item? I assume it could be just a service call to "broker" endpoint. or something else?

Comment: Yep, and/or use a queue mechanism for the message exchange. The latter pattern is often used if there's a stack of tasks to be done. The broker can just put them in a queue and let the processors take and process them.